# Is there a way to exempt files / folders from an AliasMatch?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, alias

I'm looking to do a general alias for my website to an application home directory, but there are some files and directories that must still be vhost specific, such as caches and client-supplied files.
I can easily do this to achieve the application alias:

```
AliasMatch ^(.*)$ "/path/to/app$1"
```

But I now want to exclude certain files/folders. Right now, I have a bunch of lines like this before the AliasMatch:

```
Alias /favicon.ico "/var/www/html/vhosts/domain.name/httpdocs/favicon.ico"
```

But really that just makes it do what it would have done without the AliasMatch, in a much easier to typo and difficult to reuse way. So is there a way to simply exclude /favicon.ico, or at least utilize DocumentRoot as a constant, so I could do something like this instead?

```
Alias /favicon.ico "$DocumentRoot$/favicon.ico"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use syntax like this for AliasMatch -

```
AliasMatch ^(/(f(?!avico\.ico)|[^f]).*)$ "/path/to/app$1"
```

This will not match /favico.ico, so it will be looked in DocumentRoot of vhost

Comment: While that may work, that regex becomes rather unmaintainable once I add the remaining 7-8 exclusions Are there any other mechanisms for achieving this?

Comment: After reading documentation , i don't see nothing about it - i used mod_rewrite in this cases ( but with different folder structure certainly ) - other idea is to put all exceptions in one folder - favico can be set by HTML link AFAIK